# R change value to another

Tags: r, vector, replace

I have the following vector:

```
a <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE)
```

I would like to change `FALSE` to `TRUE` only when there are at most `n` `FALSE` values next to each other. Otherwise, the values should not be changed. 
For example, when `n = 2`, I want to obtain:

```
c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE).
```

What  is the best solution of this problem?

Comment: `rle()` and `inverse.rle()` can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rle()` and `inverse.rle()` can help:

```
a <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE)
r <- rle(a)
r$values[r$values==FALSE & r$lengths<=2] <- TRUE
inverse.rle(r)
# > inverse.rle(r)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
a[data.table(a)[, .I[all(!a) & .N <= 2],rleid(a)]$V1] <- TRUE
a
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```